# Cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_{F^S}[\frac{1}{S}]^\times$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

$\quad$Let $F$ be a number field, $\ell$ a prime, and $S$ a finite set of places of $F$ including all Archimedean places and places over $\ell$.
$\quad$Then we have
$$\mathrm{H}^1\left(G_{F,S},\mathcal{O}_{F^S}\left[\tfrac{1}{S}\right]^\times \right)\cong \mathrm{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_F\left[\tfrac{1}{S}\right])$$ and there is an exact sequence
$$0\to \mathrm{H}^2\left(G_{F,S},\mathcal{O}_{F^S}\left[\tfrac{1}{S}\right]^\times\right)\otimes\mathbb Z_\ell\to \bigoplus_{v\in S}= \left\{\begin{matrix}\begin{align*}
 &\mathbb Q_\ell/\mathbb{Z}_\ell\quad v\ {\rm non\ trivial}\\ &\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z\quad v=\mathbb R\ \mathrm{and} \ell=2\quad\to \mathbb{Q}_\ell/\mathbb{Z}_\ell \to 0
 \\&0\quad {\rm otherwise}\end{align*}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

---

$\quad$ I take Galois cohomology of $$1\to \mathcal O_{F^S}\left[\tfrac{1}{S}\right]^\times\to \prod_{v\to S}(F_v\otimes F^S)^\times\to \mathcal{O}_F^S\left[\tfrac{1}{S}\right]^\times \backslash \prod_{v\in S}(F_v\otimes F^S)^\times\to 1$$
to get these two, how about $$\mathrm{H}^i\left(G_{F,S},\mathcal{O}_{F^S}\left[\tfrac{1}{S}\right]^\times \right)\otimes \mathbb Z_\ell$$
for $i\ge 3$? I think it maybe related to cohomology of $$\mathrm{H}^i\left(G_{F,S},\mathcal{O}_{F^S}\left[\tfrac{1}{S}\right]^\times\backslash \prod_{v\in S}(F_v\otimes F^S)^\times \right) $$ but I don’t exactly know how to do it. And furthermore, I think $\mathrm{H}^i(G_{F,S},\mu_\ell)$ could be computed in some way like that.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\quad$I haven’t actually know how to draw exact sequences here, so I post the picture. I’ll turn it into text if it’s necessary (however, they are ugly).
$\quad$Taking Galois cohomology of $$1\to  \mathcal O_{F^S}[\tfrac{1}{S}]^\times \to \prod_{v\in S}F_v^\times\times\prod_{v\notin S}(F_v\otimes F^S)^\times\to \mathcal O_{F^S}[\tfrac{1}{S}]^\times \setminus\prod_{v\in S}(F_v\otimes F^S)^\times\to 1 $$we deduce[image]$\quad$The red zero follows from Hilbert 90, and $F_v^S$ denote the completion of $F^S$ along any place of $F^S$ above $v$.
$\quad$Plugging in the input of cohomology of $\mathrm{H}^i\left(G_{F,S},\mathcal{O}_{F^S}[\tfrac{1}{S}]^\times\setminus \prod_{v\in S}(F_v\otimes F^S)^\times\right)$ from class field theory, we deduce that[image]
Here, for the last row, we tensored with $\mathbb Z_\ell$ to take only the $\ell$-part. Comparing this exact sequence with $$1\to \mathrm{Ker} \to \prod_{v\notin S}\mathcal O_{F_v}^\times \times \prod_{v\in S}F_v^\times \to F^\times \setminus \mathbb A_{F,f}^\times\to \mathrm{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_F[\tfrac{1}{S}])\to 0$$
we deduce that $\mathrm{H}^1(G_{F,S},\mathcal{O}_{F^S}[\tfrac{1}{S}]^\times)\cong \mathrm{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_F[\tfrac{1}{S}])$. The description of $\mathrm H^2$ and $\mathrm{H}^3$ follows from this as well. For $i\ge 3$, we have
$$\mathrm{H}^i\left(G_{F,S},\mathcal{O}_{F^S}[\tfrac{1}{S}]^\times\right)\otimes \mathbb Z_\ell\cong \bigoplus_{v\ \mathrm{real}}\mathrm{H}^i(\mathbb{R},\mathbb C^\times)\cong \bigoplus_{v\ \mathrm{real}} \left\{\begin{matrix}
\begin{align*}&\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z\quad \ell=2\ \mathrm{and}\ i\ \rm{even}, \\ &0\quad \rm{otherwise}
\end{align*}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

---

$\quad$For $\mathrm{H}^i(G_{F,S},\mu_\ell)$, I think it’s only obvious to compute $\mathrm{H}^1(G_{F,S},\mu_\ell)$ by using Kummer theory $1\to \mu_\ell \to \mathcal{O}_{F^S}[\tfrac{1}{S}]^\times \to 1$.